# Filtering rules not working on removing bots

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, web-config, bots

My memory usage on my website causes a recycle every 10 minutes without fail on my Windows server.  Memory normally is 140mb but all of a sudden it jumps up to 600mb or more and the website needs to be recyled. I have the following entries in my web.config file to stop bots from attacking my website.  However, I get a syntax error for the  filteringRules line although my website runs ok with the updated web.config file.  I noticed that some of the bots still appear on my http log and am wondering if my filter is working properly.  Does anyone see a problem with this code or is it actually working in spite of the syntax error I get in Visual Studio?  Also, can all these bots cause memory spikes?

```
<requestFiltering>    
   <filteringRules>    !-- this line gives me a syntax error
    <filteringRule name="BlockSearchEngines" scanUrl="false" 
      scanQueryString="false">
        <scanHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add requestHeader="User-Agent" />
        </scanHeaders>
        <appliesTo>
            <clear />
        </appliesTo>
        <denyStrings>
            <clear />
            <add string="AhrefsBot" />
            <add string="MJ12bot" />
            <add string="ExtLinksfBot" />
            <add string="Yeti" />
            <add string="YandexBot" />
            <add string="SemrushBot" />
            <add string="DotBot" />
            <add string="istellabot" />
            <add string="Qwantify" />
            <add string="GrapeshotCrawler" />
            <add string="archive.org_bot" />
            <add string="Applebot" />
            <add string="ias_crawler" />
            <add string="Uipbot" />
            <add string="Cliqzbot" />
            <add string="TinEye-bot" />
            <add string="YandexImages" />

        </denyStrings>
    </filteringRule>
</filteringRules>
```

Comment: Your code sample isn't closing the `requestFiltering` tag? What syntax error are you actually getting?

Comment: I do have the requestFiltering closing tag in my web.config. I failed to show it on my code. The error message is that I have an invalid child element "filteringRules"

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of your `<filteringRules>` entry looks correct (except for the closing tag typo).

The schema for web.config that Visual Studio uses doesn't seem to include `filteringRules`, for some reason. However, that schema is independent from what IIS knows and does, so it shouldn't matter.

> Also, can all these bots cause memory spikes?

Just because a request is coming from a bot won't make it use a lot of memory. Unintentional memory spikes are usually application bugs -- memory leaks and the like. You can look at your app's memory use with a memory profiler. Allocating memory buffers and then storing references to them in a global variable/collection is a common cause. Failing to call `Dispose()` on all Disposable objects is another potential source of leaks.